# Form values are not sent back to server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

As tittle says, the form values are not sent back to server.The ajax call is ok. How to get the input values posted ? What i'm doing wrong? I'm processing the values on the next page via PHP with a simple function, so my problem must be in this script.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var email_state = false;
    $('#form').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var email = $('#email').val();
        email = email.replace(/\.(?![^@]+$)/g, '');
        if (email == '') {
            email_state = false;
            return;
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://test.com/login.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                'email_check' : 1,
                'email' : email,
            },
            success: function(response){
                if (response == 'not_taken' ) {
                    email_state = false;
                    $('#loginerror').addClass('alert').text('There was an error');
                }else if (response == 'taken') {
                    email_state = true;
                    $('#form')[0].submit();
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

My PHP code is as follows:

```
$file = fopen("questions.txt","a");
if(isset($_POST['btnsubmit'])){
$data = '-' . $_POST['email'] . '-' . $_POST['question'] . "\n";
$ret = file_put_contents('questions.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Comment: The answer should be fairly obvious. Have you checked any logs? You're trying to get a post variable labeled `password` via `$_POST['password']` but you are not supplying that, you're only sending `email` and `email_check`. This is a PHP question, not a javascript question btw. I'm not 100% sure if that errors out or just returns nothing, but I imagine that's the source of your problem.

Comment: The ajax call is just to verify if the email is already in the database and proceed with the form submision

Comment: If i remove the prevent default and   $('#form')[0].submit(); the form get's submitted  correctly but the ajax call doesn't do the check properly, and the form submits any value to the server

Comment: ah nevermind. Sorry, didn't see this was a form submit. I would verify in PHP that you're getting those values, and also make sure you're returning something, doesn't look like you are.

Comment: I'm sorry guys but now you really lost me, so which variant should i try? :)

Comment: I would try mine :D But we're all telling you generally the same thing. I just explained why it works when you remove preventDefault and why it doesn't when you have it. And also why your success function wont get hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not POST'ing `$_POST['btnsubmit']` so the if statement will never fire. I would just do

```
$file = fopen("questions.txt","a");
$data = '-' . $_POST['email'] . '-' . $_POST['question'] . "\n";
$ret = file_put_contents('questions.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

If you really want to keep the $_POST['btnsubmit'] then add it to jquery as well as question, you are missing that.

```
var question = $('#question').val();
email_check : 1,
email : email,
question: question,
btnsubmit : 1
```

and then in php

```
$file = fopen("questions.txt","a");
if($_POST['btnsubmit'] == 1){
    $data = '-' . $_POST['email'] . '-' . $_POST['question'] . "\n";
    $ret = file_put_contents('questions.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the intervention Cesar. I pasted the PHP code with at minimum, as i didn't want to charge the page with additional code. The php code has a closing }

Comment: @Lugifah have you tried to debug any of these values? It's hard to guess what your code is doing. I would make an else statement in your PHP code and have it write "error" or something to the file so at least you know more about what's wrong. Seems like the if statement is not getting hit.

Comment: @jdmdevdotnet no it does not if you are passing it through jquery. You need to specify every POST variable if you do it that way. What you are referring too is when you post from the FORM itself. <form action="..." method="post"></form>

Comment: @CesarBielich this is the case because lugifag is using preventDefault, without that the form variables will post fine.

Comment: Yes yes yes, you're right, now the form get's submitted properly

Comment: Is there a reason why should i keep the $_POST['btnsubmit']  ?

Comment: Not really, you can remove it

Comment: *you SHOULD be doing that for any POST variables you're trying to get.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the variables from your form are not getting set. Which is why it works when you remove the `preventDefault` (from your comment `If i remove the prevent default and $('#form')[0].submit(); the form get's submitted correctly`)

Take away the `e.preventDefault()`, or supply the parameters manually. via:

```
      data: {
        'email_check' : 1,
        'email' : email,
        'question' : '{question here take away brackets}',
        'btnsubmit' : 1,
      },
```

The issue with your PHP code is that your if statement is not hitting, because the value is not set. You need to set it in your data object in your ajax call, or remove the preventDefault and it will automatically POST variables from your form.

Also, not sure if you're just not posting the rest of your code, but that success function will never get hit unless you `echo` something back, via:

`echo json_encode($ret)`

Answer (score 0):

You are checking for 'btnsubmit' which hasn't been posted, which is why what is inside the if condition isn't executed. You need to provide data for 'question' as well. Use the following code:

```
$file = fopen("questions.txt","a");
if(isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['question'])){
    $data = '-' . $_POST['email'] . '-' . $_POST['question'] . "\n";
    $ret = file_put_contents('questions.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
}
```

In the ajax call:

```
data: {
    'email_check' : 1,
    'email' : email,
    'question': '{your value here}',
},
```